# How to set List<T> var to null

Tags: c#, asp.net

Because I need to finally display on the screen, the field is the filtered field.

I don't want to use `new ListLSD`, `new ListMPS`, etc.

I need to share variables `new List`.

```
[Serializable]
public class DiseasesDataInfo
{
    public String FAB { set; get; }
    public String GAA { set; get; }
    /* ... */
}

var newList = null; // Can't be set to null?

switch (ddlDiseases.SelectedValue)
{
      case DiseasesCollections.LSD:
           newList = ImportExcleInfoList.Select(x => new
           {
              x.GAA, x.GAAratio, x.GAAInhibition, x.GAAStatus,
              x.FAB, x.FABratio, x.FABStatus,
              x.GD, x.GDratio
           }).ToList();

           gvAdvanced.DataSource = newList;
           break;
    // etc.
}

gvAdvanced.DataBind();
```

Comment: The compiler cannot decuce the type. when you just assign `null` to a `var`.

Comment: When you using `var` you need a `type` on the right side. `Null` is not a type so use `object` instead of `var`. Suggestion: if you using `var` then know what it is used for!

Comment: *Don't* declare the variable outside the `case` blocks where it's used. Widening the scope of a variable is a bad idea. Using the *same* variable for different things is a bad idea as well. In fact, you probably don't need that variable at all, you could just assign the list directly to the datasource

Comment: Even better, *don't* query data and modify the UI in the same method. Create a *separate* method that performs the queries and returns a list, then assign that method's result to `gvAdvanced.DataSource`. In real applications data access is done in an entirely different class, not just a different method

Comment: What's the type of `gvAdvanced.DataSource`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I would not suggest to do it because I prefer to use models instead of anonymous types, but you can achieve it by doing something like this:

```
object newList = null; // Use object. Grid datasource accepts object
switch (ddlDiseases.SelectedValue)
{
    case DiseasesCollections.LSD:
         newList = ImportExcleInfoList.Select(x => new
         {
              x.GAA, x.GAAratio, x.GAAInhibition, x.GAAStatus,
              x.FAB, x.FABratio, x.FABStatus,
              x.GD, x.GDratio
           }).ToList();

           break;

      case DiseasesCollections.MPS:
           newList = ImportExcleInfoList.Select(x => new
           {
             x.MPS2, x.MPS2ratio, x.MPS2Status,
             x.MPS3B, x.MPS3Bratio, x.MPS3BStatus
           }).ToList();

           break;
           }

     //****** case DiseasesCollections.Other...
gvAdvanced.DataSource = newList; //Set new list here instead on every case.
gvAdvanced.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use `var` for null. You have to specify the type as the compiler cannot infer it. As you are creating anonymous types in your Linq query, you would probably have to use something like:

```
IList newList = null;
switch (ddlDiseases.SelectedValue)
{
    case DiseasesCollections.LSD:
       newList = ImportExcleInfoList.Select(x => new
       {
          x.GAA, x.GAAratio, x.GAAInhibition, x.GAAStatus,
          x.FAB, x.FABratio, x.FABStatus,
          x.GD, x.GDratio
       }).ToList();
       gvAdvanced.DataSource = newList;
       break;
   // etc.
}
```

It seems that you could also create instances of the class you specified:

```
IList<DiseasesDataInfo> newList = null;
// [...]
newList = ImportExcleInfoList.Select(x => new DiseasesDataInfo { GAA = x.GAA /* ... */}).ToList();
gvAdvanced.DataSource = newList;
```

If you don't need `newList` anywhere else outside the switch block, you could also just assign the result directly:

```
gvAdvanced.DataSource = ImportExcleInfoList.Select(x => new DiseasesDataInfo { GAA = x.GAA /* ... */}).ToList();
```

Comment: He is creating [anonymous classes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/anonymous-types). I don't think `ImportExcepInfo` is the correct type.

Comment: 'System.Collections.Generic.List<AnonymousType#1>'  Can't convert  'System.Collections.Generic.List<Genetic.GeneticBasic.DiseasesDataInfo>'

Comment: You could use the non generic `IList` and assign the result of `Select(...).ToList()` to it. That would then avoid `dynamic` which is absolutely unnecessary. `dynamic` is expensive and there's nothing really even making use of it here. `IEnumerable<object>` would be better the better choice in your example... But the variable seems unnecessary when one can adding directly to the `DataSource` property.

Comment: @pinkfloydx33  Good points. Explanations: `IList` will not work since the interface does not specify the generic `out` modifier so the cast isn't possible. Also, I chose dynamic because you'd want to access the properties of the anonymous objects somehow. Of course, if you use a specific type as below, both becomes unnecessary and you can just go with `List<DiseasesDataInfo>`.

Comment: `IList` will work (I said non-generic, so *not* `IList<object>`) and assuming that's a nornal DataSource property (like on a DataGrid or a BindingSource) then it will work just fine. The OP is only assigning to the data source (not using the properties directly) so the `dynamic` would still be unneeded. I had a sharplab example earlier to solidify these points but I closed it and it's really difficult to type those on a cell phone so we'll have to agree to disagree for now.

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 Ah seems I read your comment to quickly. Yeah I suppose that might work, *if* `DataSource` really is a normal DataSource property and *if* `newList` isn't needed anywhere else in the code (as it's declared outside the switch block). Of course, this helps only in this specific case, I also tried to address the general problem. You should add another answer with your approach.

Answer (score 2):

It's a bad idea to declare a variable outside the scope it's used, or use the same variable for different jobs. In this case the variable's value is *not* used outside a single `case` block at a time. The variable should be declared and assigned at the same time in each `case` block, eg :

```
switch (ddlDiseases.SelectedValue)
{
    case DiseasesCollections.LSD:
       var lsdList = ImportExcleInfoList.Select(x => new
       {
          x.GAA, x.GAAratio, x.GAAInhibition, x.GAAStatus,
          x.FAB, x.FABratio, x.FABStatus,
          x.GD, x.GDratio
       }).ToList();

       gvAdvanced.DataSource = lsdList;
       break;

    case DiseasesCollections.MPS:
       var mspList = ImportExcleInfoList.Select(x => new
       {
         x.MPS2, x.MPS2ratio, x.MPS2Status,
         x.MPS3B, x.MPS3Bratio, x.MPS3BStatus
       }).ToList();

       gvAdvanced.DataSource = mpsList;
       break;
}
gvAdvanced.DataBind();
```

The list could be assigned to `gvAdvanced.DataSource` directly too :

```
    case DiseasesCollections.LSD:
       gvAdvanced.DataSource = ImportExcleInfoList.Select(x => new
       {
          x.GAA, x.GAAratio, x.GAAInhibition, x.GAAStatus,
          x.FAB, x.FABratio, x.FABStatus,
          x.GD, x.GDratio
       }).ToList();
       break;
```

Comment: This is the best way to handle this, all the muckery in the other comments and answers to figure out how to keep the variable declaration where it is, is barking up the wrong tree. Instead, declare the variable where you "know" the type then the problem goes away.

Answer (score 1):

You can set a `var` to `null` because C# is strongly typed. `var` was introduced to allow us to assign anonymous types to a reference although we can use `var` with other data types aslong as the compiler can resolve the type that `var` should be. This is why we cannot do this:

```
var v;
```

Because the compiler does not know what `var` will be, in the following case the compiler will decide that `var` is actually a `string`:

```
var s = "";
```

In your case, setting `var` as `null` is something the compiler can't resolve as it could be anything that takes a `null` value (I.e. Any reference type), the compiler doesn't know that you want a list, instead you should just use an empty list:

```
var myList = new List<T>();
myList = null;
```

Or better, just declare it:

```
List<T> myList = null;
```

For reference, `var` exists to be used like, the following is an anonymous type which we must use `var` to use assign and reference to:

```
var anon = new { name = "", description = "" };
```

Comment: Creating a new empty list and then setting it to null doesn't make much sense and will only create unnecessary instantiation, assignments and garbage collection. `List<T> myList = null` is the only "correct" way.

Comment: I have that in my answer yes?

Comment: I know but why do you have that other way in there too then!? I am just saying only one of those methods makes sense. You can safely throw away the other.

Comment: Completeness. Although my answer isn't correct because I didn't catch on to the anonymous class inside the query

Answer (score 0):

You can use [dynamic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/using-type-dynamic) type which will allow you to determine the type of `newList` at runtime:

```
dynamic newList = null;
...
newList = ImportExcleInfoList.Select(x => new
{
    x.GAA, x.GAAratio, x.GAAInhibition, x.GAAStatus,
    x.FAB, x.FABratio, x.FABStatus,
    x.GD, x.GDratio
}).ToList();
...
gvAdvanced.DataSource = newList;
```

It basically tells the compiler that `newList` type unknown and might change overtime.

Answer (score -1):

Change your list initializtion to the following one:

```
List<DiseasesDataInfo> newList = null;
```

This should work. The problem is that you are using the var keyword.

Comment: Since he's constructing anonymous objects, that is not an option, because he doesn't have a type for them.